# QX11EmbedContainer equivalent in Qt5

Tags: linux, qt

In Qt4, embedding a generic X11 window was very easy:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QtGui.QWidget()
container = QtGui.QX11EmbedContainer(win)   
win_id = container.winId()

#create QProcess passing window id to process
process = QtCore.QProcess(container)
options = ["-wid", str(win_id)]
process.start(MYPROCESS, options)
```

I cannot find the equivalent steps for Qt5. I see recommendations to use 
`QWindow::fromWinId` and `QWidget::createWindowContainer`, but these have the opposite workflow and seem to be more suited to manipulating native Qt windows. To make it work, I would need to get a Qt `WId` structure of the X11 window, which I can't seem to find a way to do.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my main trouble was related specifically to the Python PyQT5 implementation. The following code snippet works for me:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QtWidgets.QWidget()   
winID = int(win.winId())

sub_win = QtGui.QWindow.fromWinId(winID)
container = QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(sub_win)

sub_win_id = int(container.winId())

process = QtCore.QProcess(container)
```

In PyQt5, `QWidget.winId()` is returning a `SIP.NULL` pointer. You need to cast it explicitly with `int()` in order to get the same return that Qt4 had.

There may be a better way to accomplish this, but it worked for me.